Elder Scrolls-like game. Kickstarted in the mid 2000s. Had a plot aspect of an uncrossable chasm and included mechanics for waystones
I remember backing the game at the time, and it finally releasing after some years of development, although I think it never got too far out of beta. The initial graphics were very similar to The Elder Scrolls: Oblivion, to the point where I gently asked the developer, before backing, whether it was just a mod, but it was apparently something he was building in Unity. The choice of engine wound up being one of the reasons progress stalled, as he was having issues with getting the "cells" of the world to unload from memory and at one point, he posted an update about having to spend a great deal of time to update the project to the most recent version of Unity.
The opening scene had the protagonist in an exploration camp, receiving the standard letter of introduction from a relative that runs over the things the protagonist ought to know about the setting, as well as a compass. I vaguely remember that boxes were objects that you could pick up that could then contain more items, which let you surpass the grid-based inventory limits. You walked around the camp and talked to people, which introduced you to several in-game systems including how to unlock boxes, how to break breakables, and how to buy and sell items (under the guise of that you were gathering supplies for a journey). At the end of the tutorial, you were in a lecture hall at a school for explorers. I remember there were a number of books and images that you could view in that building about attempts to cross that chasm, with three that come to mind involving balloons, catapults, and stilts. I want to say that there was something in the chasm which ate away at things in it, or floating above it, which made crossing difficult to impossible. Your relative (an uncle?) was one of the people obsessed with crossing, and had left you a message before he left on his last voyage.
From there, my memories get a little bit hazier, but I remember that on campus, you got to do a few things that determined what skills/class you were aiming for, you could grab some supplies, and you got an introduction to a form of fast travel that involved getting onto a chain of waypoints and being able to travel between then at high speed, with the promise that one of the skills you could pick up would allow you to lay such waypoints (I think in the form of stones), and eventually get quests that would reward you for setting them up for future travellers. Something in your uncle's message led you to a remote house, whereupon you were attacked by a floating eye, which resulted in the house catching on fire. And... past that, I don't remember if I got any further.
I remember that the creator put out a tool letting people write books to be included in the game, and that we were able to vote on further features, two of which included a grappling hook system and an unlockable hang glider. I vaguely remember that development slowed, and eventually stopped, due to a combination of the developer realizing it was too much for a single developer, and that he'd become a father, which severely cut down on his free time. I think I checked it out again 4-5 years ago, and found that the game had become unplayable because the UI was built for a fixed resolution and was therefore unusably tiny. I think it was released on Steam, and might still be up there. The only other thing I remember was that there was an odd bug where you couldn't name a profile "Test" and I think it would crash the program. I can only assume that there was some quirk of the framework they were using to save profiles that had that as a reserved value.
I don't know if the game was released on any consoles. I played on the PC.
Games suggested that I have ruled out

Witanlore: Dreamtime - Interesting game, and another one abandoned by the creator in early access, but I remember this being a solo dev effort, and I don't recall anything about ursine or tribal mechanics


Mid 2000s was when Unity first released

Huh. Which means I may be off on my timeline. I remember Oblivion as having been fairly recently released.

Could it be Witanlore: Dreamtime? I haven't played it, but I recall it being Oblivion-like and being abandoned by the developer.

@galacticninja I read through the description, and unfortunately, none of it strikes me as familiar.

@FuzzyBoots If you specifically mean Kickstarter, they didn't launch until 2009, so your timeline is definitely off. Of course it could have been an alternative crowdfunding platform, but I don't remember that being a big thing mid-2000s.

@mohirl: You are right, although it did lead to finding a search that led me in the correct direction.

So, it turns out I had the timeframe all messed up. The project wasn't until 2011, and started on Indiegogo. Frontiers by Lars Simkin.

FRONTIERS blends the feel of first-person RPG classics like Daggerfall with the relaxing tempo and simplicity of a point-and-click adventure.

From the Kickstarter:

I can still remember the first time I played Daggerfall. Yes, it was uglier than a monkey's armpit and controlled worse than a bumper car on a frozen lake.
But it also created the feeling of a world that lived on even after I'd stopped playing, and that feeling still sticks with me all these years later. A world where you could spend hours searching every pixelated nook and cranny. A world of potential. A world of EXPLORATION...
...and then a Dragonling would chomp my face because I hadn't spent ten hours grinding in the easy regions. Arg! So frustrating!
Other games have touched on that elusive feeling, especially Elder Scrolls and early Fallout games, but as fun as they are and as much as I love hardcore RPG mechanics, I've always dreamt of a game that emphasized exploration above all else.

Backstory mentioning the rift

Waystones

I finally found it by searching my email for Kickstarter elder scrolls and found this in an update:

There's also the fallout from the initial comparison to Elder Scrolls games. It was a great way to convey my goals up front but as the endgame approaches I wonder if it wasn't a bad idea. Kickstarter and Greenlight are mediums where people read a bit about what they're getting into, so I could always count on people using TES & Daggerfall as a mental starting point and then taking the time to differentiate it from FRONTIERS. But if someone just hears 'Elder Scrolls clone' without hearing the rest - an inevitability when I can't course-correct the conversation - FRONTIERS is just going to confuse them. But oh well, what's done is done.

The Final Update mentioned that the issues that led to the project ending were a combination of code rewrites and fatherhood. And, looking at the community, the primary issue was that the last update involved degrading the graphics down to "something like Minecraft" to solve the problem of Unity at the time not providing an easy way to unload scenes/textures.

Can't say I blame you. It's been almost two years since the last big update. Unless you're one of the backers who contacted me directly you'd have no way to know I was still hard at work. Raising a kid while working full-time doesn't leave much time for development, but I've averaged a few hours of work a night with occasional full-time sprints during weekends & vacations.

....

The reality that the game might never be finished set in. That was an actual thing that could happen. Not because I'd given up, or because I couldn't handle it emotionally, or because the heat-death of the universe had finally set in. It might never be finished because I was incapable of finishing it for reasons beyond my understanding or control. Just... kill me already. I could barely process this impending failure privately, let alone publicly.

....

I'm getting old. I've been working late into the evening on something or another for my entire adult life and I'm ready to put that activity on pause and just be part of my family for a while.

Alpha Gameplay



Thread about the degradation of graphics

Performance. Unity is terrible for open-world games with streaming terrain. It was even worse years ago when development started. Many of Unity's optimizations work only in the editor when the level (yeah, a closed fixed level) is loaded all at once. Then Unity welds meshes, precomputes lights and shadows, calculates culling and occlusion with binary space partitioning. In a streaming open world, none of that can happen.
Even worse: once you load a texture in a level, you can't unload it, ever. Only by loading a new level can you regain your memory.
Unity is better now (you can now unload textures), but you can't "just upgrade" the engine; you have to rewrite a big part of your game to make things work. Assuming you're already an expert in the new Unity stuff, which takes time to learn.
So, option 1: spend one or two more years rewriting the core of the game to solve SOME of Unity's limitation (and then there's a new unity). Option 2: lower the graphics until the game runs at 60 FPS and finally release.

